# Wrong solution in a geometry problem

Tags: geometry, findinstance

I try to solve the simple problem of finding (integer numbers) for the sides of a triangle when its perimeter is 90 and its area is twice, three times or four times this number. My approach is this:

```
Grid[{#, 
FindInstance[
 a + b + c == 90 && a > b > c > 0 && 
  Area@SSSTriangle[a, b, c] == #*90, {a, b, c}, Integers, 
 3]} & /@ {2, 3, 4}, Frame -> All]
```

However the second solutions when the area is double and triple does not correspond to the sides of a triangle as it should comply a<b+c and this is apparent when you try to calculate the area of the triangle by `Area@SSSTriangle[50, 27, 13]` which reports

SSSTriangle::tri: The triangle side 50 should be less than sum of sides 27 and 13.

How the third condition is fullfiled in the FindInstance ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: No bug, just a surprise. It arises from how the evaluation proceeds. `In[2172]:= Area@SSSTriangle[a, b, c]

Out[2172]= 1/4 Sqrt[
 Abs[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)]]` This is what `FindInstance` actually has to work with.

Comment: Based on @DanielLichtblau 's comment adding in the constraint `a <= b + c` gets the desired results.

Comment: @JimB: It should be `a < b+c` to exclude degenerated cases.

Comment: @user64494  Sounds good but degenerates aren't all bad.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Correct. So the expression of the area is evaluated before the warning message. The warning should be triggered before for getting the correct result without the additional constrain.

Comment: However when Heron's formula (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronsFormula.html) is used for the calculation of the area the constrain is not needed 
With[{t = (a + b + c)/2},
 Grid[{#, 
     Flatten@FindInstance[
       a + b + c == 90 && a > b > c > 0 && 
        Sqrt[t (t - a) (t - b) (t - c)] == #*90, {a, b, c}, Integers, 
       3]} & /@ {2, 3, 4}]]

Comment: I don't understand. What is the warning message?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau When it comes to calculate the Area@SSSTriangle[50, 27, 13] 
which is one triplet from the wrong return solutions mathematica replies  "SSSTriangle::tri: The triangle side 50 should be less than sum of sides 27 and 13", which is correct. However this error is not triggered when the solution is sought and the wrong result appears in the solutions.

Comment: It cannot be triggered by the original code, and for the reason I gave. FindInstance never sees Area@… and so it has no way to “check” its result. (I use quotes because removal of e.g. parasite solutions is probably not something FindInstance does directly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to add the triangle inequality `a < b + c`:

```
Grid[
  {#, FindInstance[
        a + b + c == 90 && a > b > c > 0 && a < b + c && 
        Area@SSSTriangle[a, b, c] == #*90, 
        {a, b, c}, Integers, 3]
  }& /@ {2, 3, 4}, 
  Frame -> All
]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & \{\{a\to 41,b\to 40,c\to 9\}\} \\
 3 & \{\{a\to 39,b\to 36,c\to 15\}\} \\
 4 & \{\{a\to 36,b\to 29,c\to 25\}\} \\
\end{array} $$

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)
```

Or using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = DeleteDuplicates[
  Solve[
   {a + b + c == 90, a + b > c, a + c > b, b + c > a,
    Mod[Area[SSSTriangle[a, b, c]], 90] == 0},
   {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers],
  Sort[Values[#1]] == Sort[Values[#2]] &]

(* {{a -> 9, b -> 40, c -> 41}, {a -> 15, b -> 36, c -> 39}, 
    {a -> 25, b -> 29, c -> 36}} *)
```

Checking,

```
{a + b + c, Area[SSSTriangle[a, b, c]]/90} /. sol

(* {{90, 2}, {90, 3}, {90, 4}} *)
```